# wpa_supplicant.conf not used by debian 12 when booted?

Tags: debian, boot, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I'm creating a debian 12 from an image with the Balenaetcher tool. Once the SSD is written, I create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file via a text editor in the `/boot/firmware/` partition so that it can be used to configure the card without logging into Debian.
But this file is never used when the Linux boots, so my wlan0 wifi interface is not configured.
Just for information, the interface works if I put in the `/etc/network/interface` file the right information such as:

```
auto wlan0=wifi-home
iface wifi-maison inet dhcp
#wpa-ssid "mySSID
#wpa-psk "myPass"
```

---

`wpa_supplicant.conf` as requested in comments :

```
country=fr
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={  scan_ssid=1  ssid="monSSID"  psk="monPass" }
```

Comment: Why not place it in `/ect/wpa_supplicant/`?

Comment: Where would it be documented that placing wpa_supplicant.conf in /boot/firmware (this directory too, where is it documented?) will make Wifi work immediately? Note: the question is about Debian 12, it is not about RaspberryPi

Comment: By default, I don't have access to the debian OS. i've used this to configure an Raspberry Pi for Headless Boot
When creating the SD card, if you want to have the wifi configured without having access to the OS, you need to create this file in the partition named boot under Windows and Mac. This file will be read automatically at boot time by the Linux and then deleted.

Comment: You are describing a behavior not available from Debian. This is a Raspberry Pi OS behavior (from what I could read) that you assume will be available on Debian because it's based on Debian. You should not assume this.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was a standard debian manipulation. Is there another way to set the SSID / Pass without logging into debian?

Comment: Welcome, please add the content of `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: `pi@smartphoton:~$ sudo cat /boot/firmware/wpa_supplicant.conf 
country=fr
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
 scan_ssid=1
 ssid="monSSID"
 psk="monPass"
} 
`